# BioPython: Flattening JSON Key-Values to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, biopython

I need a crawler module that can collect paper title, author list, publication time, and abstract from PUBMED for several given keywords (e.g. Eye) and a pre-specified time window (e.g., 01/01/2015 – 08/06/2018), and the retrieved data should be saved in the JSON format. I am able to scrape the website and store data in the JSON file.

However, I am unable to flatten out the nested key-values to create a data frame, with column heads as "paper title, author list, publication time, and abstract".

Please help.

Effort so far is as follows:

```
import Bio
from Bio import Entrez
import json
import requests 
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint 
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize  
import pandas as pd

def search(query):
    Entrez.email = 'my.email@gmail.com'
    handle = Entrez.esearch(db='pubmed', sort='relevance', retmax='100', retmode='xml', term=query)
    results = Entrez.read(handle)
    return results

def fetch_details(id_list):
    ids = ','.join(id_list)
    Entrez.email = 'my.email@gmail.com'
    handle = Entrez.efetch(db='pubmed', retmode='xml', id=ids)
    results = Entrez.read(handle)
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = search('Eye')
    id_list = results['IdList']
    papers = fetch_details(id_list)
    for i, paper in enumerate(papers['PubmedArticle']): 
        print("%d) %s" % (i+1, paper['MedlineCitation']['Article']['ArticleTitle']))
```

Comment: Could you post a complete, copy-pastable example of the raw JSON that needs to be converted into a DataFrame?

Comment: Thank you for the response. The 
 link to JSON file is:              
                                        
                                        
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZVwvtKih9B84FZ99pr-nCSDYYt0jf_ft/view?usp=sharing